# Creating index takes very long time

Tags: mongodb

I created a collection in MongoDB consisting of **11446615** documents.

Each document has the following form:

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("4e03dec7c3c365f574820835"), 
 "httpReferer" : "http://www.somewebsite.pl/art.php?id=13321&b=1", 
 "words" : ["SEX", "DRUGS", "ROCKNROLL", "WHATEVER"],     
 "howMany" : 3 
}
```

**httpReferer**: just an url

**words**: words parsed from the url above. Size of the list is between 15 and 90.

I am planning to use this database to obtain list of webpages which have similar content.

I 'll by querying this collection using **words** field so I created (or rather started creating) index on this field:

```
db.my_coll.ensureIndex({words: 1})
```

I started creating index about 3 hours ago and it doesn't seem like it could finish in another 3 hours.

How can I increase speed of indexing? Or maybe I should use completely another approach to this problem? Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nope, indexing is slow for large collections. You can create the indexing in the background as well:

`db.my_coll.ensureIndex({words:1}, {background:true});`

Creating the index in the background will be slower and result in a larger index. However, it won't be used until the indexing is complete, so in the meantime you'll be able to use the database normally and the indexing won't block.

Comment: I just checked in mongodb.log that creating index for whole collection would take ca. 30 hours which is way too long. I 'll try to create index before adding data to it.

Comment: I tried another approach. Indexing before inserting data to the collection. Results were even worse. Before it took 5.5 hours to insert data and ca. 30 hours to index it.

Adding data to preindexed collection would take a few days.

Comment: Creating the index before inserting will be slower. It is more efficient, and faster, if you can wait to create the index till after the data has been imported.

Comment: shards for huge collections may help here. If the huge collection is well balanced between two or more shards, indexing time will be # of shards time faster since index creation will run in parallel

Comment: how is it possible that it would take longer to add data to a preindexed collection? That doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Alex, after indexes are created, all new write ops will have to update the existing indexes. For example, you have index on username and as new usernames are added to the collection the index 'username' needs to be updated for every write operation

Comment: Curious - why would creating an index in the background result in a larger index?

Comment: I am not sure if there were some changes made to the way indexes are created, but it seemed that letting Mongo create indexes automatically in the background is faster than doing it straight away. At least that seemed to be the case for 45 million document collection running mongorestore on version 4.x

Answer (score 4):

Background indexes also have some issues.

1. If anything it should take longer due to the load on your server.
2. If interrupted for some reason it will restart as a foreground build

If you have a replica set I prefer to do a "rolling index build".

1. Take a secondary out of replica set
2. Build index
3. Insert secondary back into replica set

I think this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, resolved through a work around with the following steps.

1. rename the collection you are trying to create index.

> **db.<existing_collection>.renameCollection("<rename_collection>");**

2. execute the index query.

> **db.<existing_collection>.createIndex({<option_goes_here>});**

3. Transfer data from rename_collection to existing_collection.

> **db.<rename_collection>.find().forEach(function(doc){db.<existing_collection>.insert(doc);});**

4. remove the renamed collection collection

> **db.<rename_collection>.drop();**

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, there are two great options for creating large indexes in MongoDB replica sets and sharded clusters. Option #1 is widely recommended, however the index I had to create was going to take around *10 days per node* running the database from a traditional HDD. This is not viable for large replica sets/sharded clusters, so Option #2 was much faster for me

**Option #1** - [Rolling Index Build](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/)

**Option #2** - Create the index on one node (per replica set), backup the database files, and then copy the database backup to all the other node(s). You will just want to make sure the Oplog is large enough to capture the time window it takes to fully transfer the database backup. The index build will also complete order(s) of magnitude faster if you create the index on a node with the database running on a SSD or NVMe